# Find string, ignore partials and add to list

Tags: vb.net, string, list, search

I have a tab separated file containing a large number of lines.  I'm trying to output the first and last lines in this file which contain an exact instance of a string, without outputting lines which contain partial instances. For example, I am searching all lines in the file containing a tab-separated "100" and returning only these lines and not those which contain 100584 5416100 etc. My file might look like:

```
15131  4845154 78465500 100  1784874  <-- should be found
10048  7846545 78464989 875  9897845  <-- should not be found
74654  4784848 99135456 100  7465464  <-- should be found
10078  8786468 84686446 875  8784845  <-- should not be found
```

I thought the best way would be to populate a list:

```
Dim myList As List(Of String)
myList = IO.File.ReadLines(SomeFile).OfType(Of String).Where(Function(s) s.Contains("100")).ToList
```

Then, myList.first and myList.last returns the respective lines.  This works fine, yet the code above also yields the first and last lines which also contain the partial instances.  How can this be resolved? Huge thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Contains("100")` to read `Contains(" 100 ")`. Note the spaces around the number.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your pointer had me re-look at this.  I solved the issue with Contains(vbTab & "100" & vbTab)

Comment: Awesome. You can set my answer to accepted or add your own and accept that.